# stretching background image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, stretch

I have a background image with size **1x947 px**,

> the problem is it's a **gradient color**, so i only use **repeat-x**,
>   but when the page height **over 947 px**, it shows it background
>   color,

```
background-image:url(bg.gif);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

how to **stretch it**?

[image]

here's the code example on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K9cUd/1/

Comment: Can you put something on http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can play around with it?

Comment: Can't you just set the background colour to one of the two colours in the gradient? Then it will at least flow smoothly out of the gradient.

Comment: Hi there, Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

Hard to tell without the code or an example.

You could use CSS3's

`background-size: 100%;`

which should stretch it to the entire page size.

You might need to do

`background-size: 0 100%;` or `background-size: 0% 100%;`

so the width does not change.

You can read more here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm

And the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size

Comment: And of course, it should go without saying (but you really have to), only works in modern browsers.

Comment: FYI, I was only able to make this work on FF or IE9 if you set `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and `background-size: 100% 100%;` It worked with only the Y axis and using repeat-x in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use percentages use:

```
    background-size: cover;
```